# 'React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h' error with multiple schemas in React Native Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, development-environment

I have 2 schemas in my react native app. These schemas are working fine for Android, although when attempting to run for IOS, I'm pretty sure I'm setting something wrong with my schemas on xcode, just don't know what, both schemas give me this same error. The error I get is:

[image]

This is my `podfile`:

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, min_ios_version_supported
prepare_react_native_project!

flipper_config =  FlipperConfiguration.disabled

linkage = ENV['USE_FRAMEWORKS']
if linkage != nil
  Pod::UI.puts "Configuring Pod with #{linkage}ally linked Frameworks".green
  use_frameworks! :linkage => linkage.to_sym
end

abstract_target 'defaults' do
  config = use_native_modules!
  use_frameworks! :linkage => :static

  # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # Hermes is now enabled by default. Disable by setting this flag to false.
    # Upcoming versions of React Native may rely on get_default_flags(), but
    # we make it explicit here to aid in the React Native upgrade process.
    :hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled],
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    # Enables Flipper.
    #
    # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
    # you should disable the next line.
    :flipper_configuration => flipper_config,
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  target 'Development' do
    inherit! :complete
  end

  target 'Production' do
    inherit! :complete
  end  

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(
      installer,
      # Set `mac_catalyst_enabled` to `true` in order to apply patches
      # necessary for Mac Catalyst builds
      :mac_catalyst_enabled => false
    )
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]'] = "arm64"
      end
    end
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
  end
end
```

Xcode setup:

[image]

[image]